# Converted String to float, program doesn't say data

Tags: c#, discord.net

I'm trying to get the short/string to be added to a user's already existing short data. 
I converted a string to an short here:

```
string[] args = text.Split(' ');
received = args[0];
username = args[6];

if (whitelisted.ContainsKey(username))
    Program.Deposit();

...

public static string received;
public static string username;

public static uint GetPayed(string received)
{
    ushort payed;

    if (UInt16.TryParse(received, out payed))
        return payed;
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to write it using a function in the program.cs class, which can be seen here:

```
var checkedaccount = UserAccounts.GetOrCreateAccount(MinecraftClient.Utilities.GetWhitelisted(MinecraftClient.ChatBots.Deposit.username));
                 checkedaccount.Deposited += MinecraftClient.ChatBots.Deposit.GetPayed(MinecraftClient.ChatBots.Deposit.received);
                 UserAccounts.SaveAccounts();
```

I tried deleting my data json to see if the action would cause it to create itself again, which it didn't. When trying a different command concerned with player data, it did however.

Comment: What exactly is happening with this code? Are you facing any errors?

Comment: No errors, just isn't writing data to the json.

Comment: Did you debug the code? What value you are getting in `checkedaccount.Deposited` before `UserAccounts.SaveAccounts();` ? What value do you have in `MinecraftClient.ChatBots.Deposit.received` ?

Comment: I tested, and they seem to not be returning anything.

Answer (score 0):

If the string value you are trying to convert is a float then `Uint16.TryParse` will probably fail. You can convert into a float first and round to an int.

```
payed = (int)Math.Round(float.Parse(recieved));
return payed;
```